# Вычислить значение функции y

Tags: c++

Нужно вычислить значение функции y.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что-то такое сделал, не знаю правильно это или нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, ".1251");
    double y = NULL;
    int n;
    system("cls");
    start:
    cout << "Введите значение n: ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 6)
    {
        y = n * (n - 2)*(n - 1);
    }
    if (n == 10)
    {
        y = pow(2, 28 - n);
    }   
    if (n == 18)
    {
        y = (n-10);
    }
    if (y == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Вы ввели неправильное значение.\n";
        goto start;
    }
    cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а Вы откомпилируйте и запустите программу, и узнаете

Comment: очевидно факториала в последнем случае не хватает...

Comment: вам нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает все эти значения, а потом вызвать эту функцию с  заданными аргументами [0; 20], если я правильно понел требование задачи, но я не уверен в этом

Comment: Зачем здесь что-то считать? Эти три числа известны заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток.

Как уже указали в комменте, нет факториала. Его можно вычислить рекурсивной функцией

```
double fact(x)
{
    if (x == 1) return 1;
    return x * fact(x - 1);
}
```

Ну, добавлю, что следующее неверно

```
double y = NULL;
...
if (y == NULL)
```

В данном контексте работать будет, но так писать код не следует, потому что NULL - это макроопределение для указателя, которое заменяется на 0. Для того, чтобы проверить, что пользователь ввел корректный n необходимо использовать один из вариантов:

- связанная стуктура `if / else if / else`
- `switch / case`
- отдельная переменная - флаг. (хуже всего)

Например:

```
if (n == 6)
{
    y = n * (n - 2)*(n - 1);
}
else if (n == 10)
{
    y = pow(2, 28 - n);
}   
else if (n == 18)
{
    y = fact(n-10);
}
else
{
    cout << "Ошибка! Вы ввели неправильное значение.\n";
    goto start;
}
```

Напоследок, для самостоятельного решения. Исправте программу, чтобы не использовался оператор goto.